# Toggle iOS 8 predictive text while typing

Tags: keyboard, uitextfield, ios8

When you enable `autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes` in a texfield. In iOS 8 you have this predictive text activated.

I would like to be able to toggle the predictive inputView while typing.

```
if (condition) { 
    self.textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes; 
} else {
    self.textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; 
}

[self.textField reloadInputViews];
```

My keyboard is black transparent. And this hides the predictive input view behind the keyboard.

[image]

I would like to know if it's possible to hide it totally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (Xcode 6.0.1) there is no documented feature to enable/disable predictive bar on the go. But there is a way to toggle it programmatically. I also tried some other methods (eg. `setNeedsLayout` on input view) but this is the only one that works.

```
[textfield resignFirstResponder];
[textfield becomeFirstResponder];
```

It even works in an animation block but awful animations, don't use it :]

Comment: For the record, I tried doing this on the equivalent of textField immediately after its creation, and this did not make any difference.

Comment: This works only if you change text field's `autocorrectionType` when the keyboard is already visible.